Animated TV series about blood cells, red blood cells as firefighters and white cells as commandos
The series was about blood cells, it shows the red blood cells as firefighters and white cells as commandos and police and they use a train to move through the blood vessels. It was similar to once upon a time life. Watched it like 13-16 years ago. In the end of the series or one of the episodes they show about blood cancer. and also the first episode(s) shows the bone marrow and how white cells are produce.

Could have been this one. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0284735/

I only know the German title which is "Es war einmal... das Leben" but it has an english dubbed Version.
It has white blood cells looking like poice officers and episodes about bone marrow and blood cancer.
The only thing I couldn't find in this series is using a train to move through the blood vessels.

It must be Ozzy & Drix

Ozzy & Drix (also known as The Fantastic Voyage Adventures of Osmosis Jones & Drixenol and Osmosis Jones: The Animated Series) is an American animated television series based on the Warner Bros. film Osmosis Jones and it was produced by Warner Bros. Animation. It takes place inside the body of teenager Hector Cruz (referred to by the characters as "the City of Hector"). 
A year after Ozzy and Drix defeated Thrax and saved Frank from dying in Osmosis Jones, Ozzy and Drix chase a scarlet fever bacterium (possibly thanks to Frank resuming his poor eating habits) and run into Leah and the girls. During the chase, Ozzy, Drix, and the germ get sucked up from Frank by a mosquito and arrive on a teenager named Hector Cruz. After some initial problems with their new home, both are installed as Private Investigators, vowing to protect the wellbeing of Hector from any viral threat, not to mention, help him through the changes in his teen years.

Below is the intro




it's not it.on that series they only use the train to move. and in the end of the series or one of the episodes they show about blood cancer

@Amirmehdi mention those details in question itself, as currently provided details are too less.

thanks for the help, but as I said it was a long time ago I don't know most of the detail.

The series could be:

Body talk: TV series of films about how the body works, with cartoons.
The Magic School Bus: TV series (1994–1997)

IMDB

